# Password recovered from Keychain fails to decrypt volume

Tags: disk-utility, password, keychain, encryption

I lost my Mac computer and recovered some items from a backup. One was an a disk image with extension `.dmg`, with 400 MB, encrypted with `Disk Utility`, and last changed on 8th November 2018. The password was saved in the login keychain and I used to decrypt the volume by just double-clicking it. The password shows a date of 14th May 2018.

I recovered the password from the keychain but it fails to decrypt the volume. I am confident that it's the right password because I confirmed that other passwords in the same keychain are accurate, and because Keychain Access would not show the password in plain text if the file were corrupted or if I had forgotten the login password.

The only possibility that I see is that the Disk Utility encryption algorithm changed between High Sierra in 2018 and Mojave in 2019, but this seems far-fetched because then users could not share an encrypted volume between OS versions.

What other reasons could `Disk Utility` encryption be failing with the right password?

Comment: Check Keychain for other similarly named passwords. The App has been known to keep old copies. You may find one from say 18 June 2018.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I double-checked and confirmed that the Keychain has no other similarly named items. In alphabetical order the previous item is `eduroam` and the next item is `ftp.gnu.org`.